# (Automatically) display hexadecimal strings in RStudio console in their respective color?

Tags: r, colors, console, rstudio, crayon

I am aware that packages like `crayon` can make the RStudio console output appear in all kinds of colors when manually asked to do so with functions such as `blue()` (https://github.com/r-lib/crayon).

What would really be awesome, however, would be a package or RStudio Addin that automatically colors strings in the console if they are color character names or hexadecimal strings. Take this vector as an example:

```
c("blue", "#ff00ff", "#CCE6FF")
```

printing it in the console would look like this
[image]

Is there a way to make this happen?

**EDIT:** Apparently not - see my reply to this question.

Comment: I was referred to a github issue that is adressing this exact issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/5424

There is no way to make this happen, yet.
If there ever will be a solution, it will probably be announced in that issue.